Trying to find the name of a TV Series shown in NZ late 70s early 80s
NZ was a late release market at the time - so it may have been made in the early 70s...
This TV series was set in Meso-America During the days of the Mayans or the Incas, and was largely a political story.
I remember the sets as being pretty sweeping and quite awesome BUT I was a young teenager at the time with limited experience of movies and well done video productions so it could easily have been somewhat amateurish.  
I also have a vague recollection that the sets were filled with very vivid colours - with a heavy weighting towards yellow, gold and red colours.
The language was English - and it seems like it was focused at the young adult market.  But like I mentioned - I was a very young teenager when watching it so I could be remembering this wrong...

What was the show about? "Meso-American politics" doesn't tell me a whole lot. Can you remember any plots from specific episodes? What characters were there? What problems were they facing?

It is hard to remember specific episodes - this was around 35 years ago!     BUT I do remember young adults or teenagers trying to get away from priests who MAY have been trying to sacrifice them.     There were pyramids - and some of the plot might have been about figuring out secret passages in the pyramids or royal buildings

There were also definitely Kings and Priests who were competing politcally

I hear ya! I remember watching (American) shows like "Welcome Back Kotter" and "Room 222", and I can still recite catch phrases from them. But I couldn't tell you what actually happened in a single episode! Memory's funny that way.
